# Recursive function JavaScript concat array result - ImageJ

Tags: javascript, file, recursion, imagej

I tried to make a JavaScript code for ImageJ, which has to goal to allow me to select a directory, and return me all jpg and jpeg files in the directory and sub-directories.

I have do this code, it works well for direct children, it calls getJpeg on subdirectories (I have verify it with some IJ.log), but the jpeg Array is not concatenated with the results of recursive calls

Have you an idea?

```
importClass(Packages.ij.IJ);
importClass(Packages.ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager);
importClass(Packages.ij.gui.GenericDialog);
importClass(Packages.ij.io.OpenDialog);
importClass(Packages.java.io.File);

var dirstr = IJ.getDirectory("Choose the stacks folder");
var jpeg = getJpeg(dirstr);

for (var i = 0; i < jpeg.length; i++) {
        IJ.log(jpeg[i]);
}

function getJpeg(dirst) {
        var dir = new java.io.File(dirst);
        var names = dir.listFiles();
        var jpeg = new Array();
        for (var i = 0 ; i < names.length; i++) {
            if(names[i].isDirectory()){
                jpeg.concat(getJpeg(names[i].getPath()));
                continue;
            }
            var namest = names[i].getName();
            if (namest.match(/.*\.jpg|jpeg/)) {     
                    var path = names[i].getPath();
                    jpeg.push(path);
            }
        }
        return jpeg;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: For Array I think it will be push() not concat(). check the method properly

Comment: Thank, I will try that, but I think I will have an array in the array.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_concat_array.asp

EDIT;
I saw my error with post you the doc, the concat is a result of the function, I have to do, 
   jpeg = jpeg.concat(getJpeg(names[i].getPath()));

I am so idiot

Comment: @Zeldarck Does that mean you solved your question? If so, please post your solution as an answer and mark it as solved. For your code, I recommend to use [script parameters](https://imagej.net/Script_Parameters) instead of `GenericDialog` and `OpenDialog`. For further questions about ImageJ, the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) is the best place to ask.

Comment: The code it's not for me, I wait the return of my mate to mark this answered :)
the question was more on javascript problem than ImageJ, think it was better place here, but thank for the advice :)

I will look at script parameters, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from a missread from concat documentation ( w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_concat_array.asp ). Have to put 
    jpeg = jpeg.concat(getJpeg(names[i].getPath()));